# "Uncaught Error: element not specified" when integrate Facebook Javascript SDK with Turbolink (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, facebook-javascript-sdk, turbolinks

I'm using Rails 4 with Turbolink and want to integrate Facebook Javascript SDK. If turn off Turbolink, everything seems okay. But when not, this error always appears when I call FB.ui:

```
  Uncaught Error: element not specified                              all.js:82
```

This can be solved if I refresh the page.

Before this error, I have solved "FB not defined" error by this code:

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    $(function() {
      FB.init({
        ...
      })
    });
  }
```

and Facebook JS SDK is got by:

```
  <script src='//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
```

I have read a lot of relative questions and answers but still haven't had solutions for this issue. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is Turbolink doesn't reload all stylesheet when loading a new page.
You can make a function, then every time the page load, this function will be call again

```
fb_register = ->
  # Your code here
```

And then, add this below

```
$(document).ready(fb_register)
$(document).on('page:load', fb_register)
```

Comment: I have tried to load it again each page load but it still not work. This issue may occur by the code in Facebook Javascript SDK.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you put inside the fb_register function?